How can I disable the "lightbulb tip" in Android Studio when moving the cursor to the front of the line?
When I move the cursor to the front of the line in Android Studio this lightbult thing is keep appearing, the bad thing is that you cannot click it through, so when you would like to put the cursor at the front of the line for example to modify a variable's visibility like from public to private for example this thing keeps reappearing making it very difficult to do so.
Is there a way to completly remove that lightbulb thing?
Thanks in advance.
This is what I'm talking about:


Search for "bulb" in Android Studio Settings and in Appearance uncheck "Show intention bulb"
Android Studio settings showing Show Intention Bulb setting

Wow never thought it would actually show up as "bulb" in the settings, thank you Ashish.
